# OLAP Web Visualization and Reporting Recommendations

Tags: apache-flex, reporting-services, reporting, jasper-reports, olap

I am preparing an offer for a customer. They proide weekly data to different organizations. There is huge amount data suits OLAP that needed to be visualized with charts and pivot tables on web and custom reports will be built by non-it persons (an easy gui). They will enter a date range, location which data columns to be included and generate report and optionally export the data to Excel. They currently prepare reports with MS Excel with Pivot Tables and but they need a better online tool now to show data to their customers. Tables are huge and  need of drill-down functionality. My current knowledge Spring, Flex, MySql, Linux. I have some knowledge of PostgreSQL and MSSQL and Windows. What is the easiest way of doing this project. Do you think that  SSRP (haven't tried yet) and ASP.NET better suits for this kind of job. Actually I prefer open source solutions. Flex have OLAP Data Grid control which do aggregation on client side. JasperServer seems promising but it seems I need enterprise version  (multiple organizations and ad hoc queries). What about Modrian + Flex + PostgreSQL solution? Any previous experience will be appreciated. Yes I am confused with options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [DynamicJasper](http://dynamicjasper.sourceforge.net/), it's based on JasperReports, but dynamically!

They have a web demo running [here](http://dynamicjasperplayground.fdvs.com.ar/ar.com.fdvs.dj.example.djApp/djApp.html), the demo shows how to customize the report results. But as your users wont be IT people, then you will need less options.

DJ Charting API does not appear in the demo, but you can check it [here](http://dynamicjasper.sourceforge.net/new%20chart%20api.html)